# How to generate n-level hierarchical JSON from Spark DataFrame

Tags: json, dataframe, apache-spark, tree

Given the following Spark dataframe:

```
+----+-----------+------+-------+
| id | parent_id | data | level |
+----+-----------+------+-------+
|  1 | null      | x    |     1 |
| 21 | 1         | y    |     2 |
| 22 | 1         | w    |     2 |
| 31 | 21        | z    |     3 |
+----+-----------+------+-------+
```

Where 'level' means the level in a tree-like structure.

How can I generate a n-level hierarchical JSON?

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "data": "x",
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "21",
      "data": "y",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "31",
          "data": "z",
          "items": []
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "22",
      "data": "w",
      "items": []
    }
  ]
}
```